# Rename unknow key from json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I been searching with no success, i would like to iterate over a json object but this have diferent names on keys, below my code

```js
  [{
    "05115156165165" :{
        "name":"John",
        "Phone":"515555"
    },
    "111111111":{
        "name":"John",
        "Phone":"515555"
    }
  }]
```

So basically i need in the following way:

```js
    [{
    "data" :{
        "name":"John",
        "Phone":"515555"
    },
    "data":{
        "name":"John",
        "Phone":"515555"
    }
  }]
```

Comment: looks like you wrapped all the objects within an object, afaik - cannot have same key (`"data"`).

Comment: Just noticed, you need to have different key for each sub object otherwise last one will overwrite older one.

Comment: @fedesc, `{a:1,a:2,a:3}=={a:3}` = the `2` and `3` "disappear".
If you look closely, you'll see that the expected is one object...

Comment: That's neither a _"json array"_ nor a _"json object"_ ([There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)). That's an array with one object

Comment: @iAmOren I did checked again that's why i removed my comment haha didn't notice the extra `{}`

Comment: Raul, perhaps you meant: `[
{"05115156165165" :{
    "name":"John",
    "Phone":"515555"
}},
{"111111111":{
    "name":"John",
    "Phone":"515555"
}}
]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to retrieve values for unknwon keys and `reduce` to transform `input` array:

```js
let input = [{
"05115156165165" :{
    "name":"John",
    "Phone":"515555"
},
"111111111":{
    "name":"John",
    "Phone":"5155557"
}
}];

let result = input.reduce((acc,cur)=> {
   Object.values(cur).forEach(
      obj => {acc.push({ data: obj });}
   )
   return acc;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is use `Object.entries` to iterate through all the keys in the object, which in this case it has only 1 that the name is unknown in every object.

```js
const data = [{
  "05115156165165": {
    "name": "John1",
    "Phone": "1111111"
  },
  "111111111": {
    "name": "John2",
    "Phone": "2222222"
  }
}]
let result = []
data.forEach(d => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(d)) {
    result.push({
      data: {
        name: value.name,
        Phone: value.Phone
      }
    })
  }
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
let data = [{
  "05115156165165": {
    "name": "John1",
    "Phone": "1111111"
  },
  "111111111": {
    "name": "John2",
    "Phone": "2222222"
  }
}]
let result = []
data.forEach(d => {
  Object.keys(d).forEach(el => {
    result.push({
      data: d[el]
    })
  })
})
console.log(result)
```